# Accessing the position [i-1] of an array in python - Filter

Tags: python, arrays, filter, index-error

I'm trying to set up a filter in Python, and I am stuck in a basic stuff.

This is the function that I have to implement:

```
y[n] = (1 − λ) · x[n] + λ · y[n − 1]
```

I'm reading an m file and applying the filter.

Here's the code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.loadtxt('acs712_192us.m')
size = len(y)

x = np.arange(0, size)

out = []

lamb = 0.9 

for i in range(0, len(y)):
    out.append(((1-lamb) * y[i]) + (lamb * out[i - 1]))

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, out)
plt.show()
```

When I run this program, get the following error:

> File "main_LI.py", line 15, in  out.append(((1-lamb) * y[i]) + (lamb * out[i - 1])) IndexError: list index out of range

I know i can't access out[-1] position (in the first loop), maybe is this the problem?

Anyone have any tips?

Thank you guys!

Comment: what does your m file contains?

Comment: Your recurrence relation doesn't seem to have a starting point.

Comment: I doubt there should be an initial value in `out` to start with.

Comment: The file is a .txt with 512 values (0 - 511). I can get the y[i]

Comment: What user2357112 said. What should `out[0]` be?

Comment: @MatheusBernardi, what is `out[0]`?

Comment: out[0] = (1 - 0.9) * y[0] + 0.9*out[-1]
I need ignore this first loop (i guess), cause this access out[-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use [negative indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) in Python. The problem is that you are providing an index that does not exist.

`out` initially is an empty list, so the problem is that you are trying to access an index that does not exist in the first iteration:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.loadtxt('acs712_192us.m')
size = len(y)

x = np.arange(0, size)

out = []

lamb = 0.9 

for i in range(len(y)):
    if i == 0:
       out.append(value) # value is what you want out[0] to be
    else:
        out.append(((1-lamb) * y[i]) + (lamb * out[i - 1]))

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, out)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for the help, sorry if was a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to do this pretty easily.

```
l = 0.9
x = np.arange(0, 10)
filtered = [x[i] if i == 0 else (1-l)*x[i] + l*x[i-1] for i in range(0,len(x))]

>>> print(filtered)
[0, 0.09999999999999998, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1000000000000005, 7.1, 8.1]
```

is this the output you expect?

Comment: That would help too! Thanks